# Keras model fitting error: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: keras

For some reason code that could be run before now shows this error. Everything is fine if I don't put callbacks in, but what is the issue even about?

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.hdf5' , monitor = ['val_accuracy'] , verbose = 1  , mode = 'max', save_best_only=True)
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)
callbacks = [checkpoint, earlystop]

...

history = model.fit(train_generator, 
          steps_per_epoch = len(train_generator),
          validation_data=val_generator, 
          validation_steps = len(val_generator),
          epochs=EPOCHS,
          callbacks=checkpoint)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-805f1a83aa3c> in <module>
      4           validation_steps = len(val_generator),
      5           epochs=EPOCHS,
----> 6           callbacks=checkpoint)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py in _save_model(self, epoch, batch, logs)
   1426       try:
   1427         if self.save_best_only:
-> 1428           current = logs.get(self.monitor)
   1429           if current is None:
   1430             logging.warning('Can save best model only with %s available, '

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You mean Veras? Try searching him on YouTube, Veras Varas a very talented guy.

Comment: `monitor = ['val_accuracy']` this is wrong, should be `monitor = 'val_accuracy'`